# Multiple carousel-indicators for Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to make two carousel-indicators with Bootstrap 3.2 which has proven difficult with my relatively beginner JavaScript skills. I've tried adding in two carousel-indicators list items, but it only effects on set of indicators. How can I have two carousel-indicators for one carousel? Thanks!

JavaScript from Bootstrap.

```
+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  // CAROUSEL CLASS DEFINITION
  // =========================

  var Carousel = function (element, options) {
    this.$element    = $(element).on('keydown.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.keydown, this))
    this.$indicators = this.$element.find('.carousel-indicators')
    this.options     = options
    this.paused      =
    this.sliding     =
    this.interval    =
    this.$active     =
    this.$items      = null

    this.options.pause == 'hover' && this.$element
      .on('mouseenter.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.pause, this))
      .on('mouseleave.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.cycle, this))
  }

  Carousel.VERSION  = '3.2.0'

  Carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION = 600

  Carousel.DEFAULTS = {
    interval: 5000,
    pause: 'hover',
    wrap: true
  }

  Carousel.prototype.keydown = function (e) {
    switch (e.which) {
      case 37: this.prev(); break
      case 39: this.next(); break
      default: return
    }

    e.preventDefault()
  }

  Carousel.prototype.cycle = function (e) {
    e || (this.paused = false)

    this.interval && clearInterval(this.interval)

    this.options.interval
      && !this.paused
      && (this.interval = setInterval($.proxy(this.next, this), this.options.interval))

    return this
  }

  Carousel.prototype.getItemIndex = function (item) {
    this.$items = item.parent().children('.item')
    return this.$items.index(item || this.$active)
  }

  Carousel.prototype.getItemForDirection = function (direction, active) {
    var delta = direction == 'prev' ? -1 : 1
    var activeIndex = this.getItemIndex(active)
    var itemIndex = (activeIndex + delta) % this.$items.length
    return this.$items.eq(itemIndex)
  }

  Carousel.prototype.to = function (pos) {
    var that        = this
    var activeIndex = this.getItemIndex(this.$active = this.$element.find('.item.active'))

    if (pos > (this.$items.length - 1) || pos < 0) return

    if (this.sliding)       return this.$element.one('slid.bs.carousel', function () { that.to(pos) }) // yes, "slid"
    if (activeIndex == pos) return this.pause().cycle()

    return this.slide(pos > activeIndex ? 'next' : 'prev', this.$items.eq(pos))
  }

  Carousel.prototype.pause = function (e) {
    e || (this.paused = true)

    if (this.$element.find('.next, .prev').length && $.support.transition) {
      this.$element.trigger($.support.transition.end)
      this.cycle(true)
    }

    this.interval = clearInterval(this.interval)

    return this
  }

  Carousel.prototype.next = function () {
    if (this.sliding) return
    return this.slide('next')
  }

  Carousel.prototype.prev = function () {
    if (this.sliding) return
    return this.slide('prev')
  }

  Carousel.prototype.slide = function (type, next) {
    var $active   = this.$element.find('.item.active')
    var $next     = next || this.getItemForDirection(type, $active)
    var isCycling = this.interval
    var direction = type == 'next' ? 'left' : 'right'
    var fallback  = type == 'next' ? 'first' : 'last'
    var that      = this

    if (!$next.length) {
      if (!this.options.wrap) return
      $next = this.$element.find('.item')[fallback]()
    }

    if ($next.hasClass('active')) return (this.sliding = false)

    var relatedTarget = $next[0]
    var slideEvent = $.Event('slide.bs.carousel', {
      relatedTarget: relatedTarget,
      direction: direction
    })
    this.$element.trigger(slideEvent)
    if (slideEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    this.sliding = true

    isCycling && this.pause()

    if (this.$indicators.length) {
      this.$indicators.find('.active').removeClass('active')
      var $nextIndicator = $(this.$indicators.children()[this.getItemIndex($next)])
      $nextIndicator && $nextIndicator.addClass('active')
    }

    var slidEvent = $.Event('slid.bs.carousel', { relatedTarget: relatedTarget, direction: direction }) // yes, "slid"
    if ($.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('slide')){
      $next.addClass(type)
      $next[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
      $active.addClass(direction)
      $next.addClass(direction)
      $active
        .one('bsTransitionEnd', function () {
          $next.removeClass([type, direction].join(' ')).addClass('active')
          $active.removeClass(['active', direction].join(' '))
          that.sliding = false
          setTimeout(function () {
            that.$element.trigger(slidEvent)
          }, 0)
        })
        .emulateTransitionEnd(Carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION)
    } else {
      $active.removeClass('active')
      $next.addClass('active')
      this.sliding = false
      this.$element.trigger(slidEvent)
    }

    isCycling && this.cycle()

    return this
  }


  // CAROUSEL PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // ==========================

  function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this   = $(this)
      var data    = $this.data('bs.carousel')
      var options = $.extend({}, Carousel.DEFAULTS, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option)
      var action  = typeof option == 'string' ? option : options.slide

      if (!data) $this.data('bs.carousel', (data = new Carousel(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'number') data.to(option)
      else if (action) data[action]()
      else if (options.interval) data.pause().cycle()
    })
  }

  var old = $.fn.carousel

  $.fn.carousel             = Plugin
  $.fn.carousel.Constructor = Carousel


  // CAROUSEL NO CONFLICT
  // ====================

  $.fn.carousel.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.carousel = old
    return this
  }


  // CAROUSEL DATA-API
  // =================

  $(document).on('click.bs.carousel.data-api', '[data-slide], [data-slide-to]', function (e) {
    var href
    var $this   = $(this)
    var $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '')) // strip for ie7
    if (!$target.hasClass('carousel')) return
    var options = $.extend({}, $target.data(), $this.data())
    var slideIndex = $this.attr('data-slide-to')
    if (slideIndex) options.interval = false

    Plugin.call($target, options)

    if (slideIndex) {
      $target.data('bs.carousel').to(slideIndex)
    }

    e.preventDefault()
  })

  $(window).on('load', function () {
    $('[data-ride="carousel"]').each(function () {
      var $carousel = $(this)
      Plugin.call($carousel, $carousel.data())
    })
  })

}(jQuery);
```

HTML markup

```
      <div id="slider1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#slider1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#slider1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#slider1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#slider1" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                <li data-target="#slider1" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                <li data-target="#slider1" data-slide-to="5"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="assets/images/slider1image1.png">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <p class="new-products">NEW PRODUCTS</p>
                        <h2>CYCLONE DRY/WET VACUUM BRAZED CORE DRILL BIT</h2>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="assets/images/slider1image1.png">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <p class="new-products">NEW PRODUCTS</p>
                        <h2>CYCLONE DRY/WET VACUUM BRAZED CORE DRILL BIT</h2>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="assets/images/slider1image1.png">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <p class="new-products">NEW PRODUCTS</p>
                        <h2>CYCLONE DRY/WET VACUUM BRAZED CORE DRILL BIT</h2>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="assets/images/slider1image1.png">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <p class="new-products">NEW PRODUCTS</p>
                        <h2>CYCLONE DRY/WET VACUUM BRAZED CORE DRILL BIT</h2>
                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#slider1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <img src="assets/images/slider1-caret-left.png">
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#slider1" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <img src="assets/images/slider1-caret-right.png">
            </a
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution isn't perfect in my case but maybe it'll helps you :)

I use the function :

```
$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
 // stuffs
}
```

This action is call when the next carousel item is gonna be changed.
Then you can add your own code, changing the CSS of the second unchangeable set of indicators.

My example :

```
$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {

    var slide_number = $('.carousel-indicators_custom')
                      .children('.active')
                      .children('.losange').attr('data-slide-to');

    // here slide number need to be parseInt and you'll certainly need to add +1 value

    $('.carousel-indicators_custom-mobile>li').css('color', '#333');
    $('.carousel-indicators_custom-mobile').find('li[data-slide-to=' + slide_number +']').css('color', '#be1522');
    $('.dynamic_puce__text').html( $('.carousel-indicators_custom-mobile').find('li[data-slide-to=' + slide_number +']').html() );
  });
```

It's a little bit ugly but it's a beginning even I'm sure their are better choices.